# Traversing through a list that has b' ahead

Tags: python, list, byte

When I write

```
a1 = list([b'1,690569\n1,315892\n1,189226\n2,834328\n2,1615927\n2,1194519\n'])
print(a1)
for edge_ in a1:
    print('edge =' + str(edge_))
    z[(edge_[0], edge_[1])] = 1
    print('edge_0 =' + str(edge_[0]))
    print('edge_1 =' + str(edge_[1]))
    print(z)
```

I get the output as

```
[b'1,690569\n1,315892\n1,189226\n2,834328\n2,1615927\n2,1194519\n']
edge =b'1,690569\n1,315892\n1,189226\n2,834328\n2,1615927\n2,1194519\n'
edge_0 =49
edge_1 =44
{(49, 44): 1}
```

Can anyone explain why it is 49 and 44? These values are coming irrespective of the element inside the list.

Comment: `ord('1')` is `49` and `ord(',')` is `44`... these are first two characters in your string (bytearray exactly).

Comment: Your list consists of **one** element, a `bytearray`. The elements of which are the integer `ord()` values of each of the characters in it.

Comment: Thanks to you both. Is there a way I can get the numbers from the string seperately? I actually want to create something like  ```z = [(1,690569):1, (1,315829) :1, (1,834328) : 1,...]```

Comment: You could do something like split the string on newlines, then split on commas to get tuples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, as others have already mentioned, your array below is a byte array. This is evident due to the 'b' at the start. You don't need to use 'list()' by the way.

```
a1 = [b'1,690569\n1,315892\n1,189226\n2,834328\n2,1615927\n2,1194519\n']
```

Given that z is an empty dictionary (i.e. `z = dict()`)
Below is just adding a tuple as a key and an integer as value:

```
z[(edge_[0], edge_[1])] = 1
```

We can see the following:

```
edge_ = a1[0] = b'1,690569\n1,315892\n1,189226\n2,834328\n2,1615927\n2,1194519\n'
edge_[0] = a1[0][0] = ord(b'1') = 49
edge_[1] = a1[0][1] = ord(b',') = 44
```

Hence `z[(edge_[0], edge_[1])] = 1` becomes:

```
z[(49, 44)] = 1
z = {(49, 44): 1}
```